# Delay in callback method processing in Google PubSub

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to pass on the message from a publisher to one of my subscribers in Google Pub/Sub. I think there is a delay in callback method being recognized late by the subscriber. Below is the example:

I have executed the callback method as below:

```
def callback(message):
    print(message.data)
    message.ack()
```

I am trying to publish the content from publisher

```
publisher.publish(topic,b"Hi hello",spam="eggs")
```

The result is b'hi hello' since I am printing only message.data in callback.

Now I am changing my call back function

```
def callback(message):
    print(message.data)
    print("hello message")
    message.ack()
```

The result when I publish the content is still b'hi hello' and it is not showing "hello message". After waiting for 2-3 minutes, it is finally showing the actual result in call back when I execute it again.

Could you please help me in addressing this delay if it is possible ?

Thank you

Comment: just guessing but try flushing the buffer `print("hello message", flush=True)`

Comment: I tried now @Darkonaut.. But it is not reflecting :(

Comment: I tried reproducing your issue, but I don't see any delay. Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of both the publisher and the subscriber?

Comment: Hi @rilla.... I am proceeding in highly synchronous way in appending strings and session to the message. I couldnt give the code because of confidentiality

Comment: I understand about the confidentiality but it would be really helpful if you can can post a minimal example that reproduces your delay issue (of course without revealing anything confidential).
With just the code you posted here, I don't get any delay, so I have no clue of what is the issue in your code and cannot help you.